# AFNetworking 2: Limit max number of concurrent Download Tasks

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm dealing with an app that implements a download queue created with AFNetworking 2.0 and I will like to know if there is a way to limit the maximum number of download tasks (`NSURLSessionDownloadTask`) running at the same time.

My final goal is that my download queue manages all the tasks so one is finished, then the next one will start.

I know that, for example, `NSOperationQueue` has the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property, but I don't know if AFNetworking 2.0 uses NSOperationQueue in a lower level with download tasks. Also, I know that `AFURLSessionManager` has an `NSArray` with all the running download tasks, but is just that, an array.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFNetworking has an operation queue, which you can set the number of concurrent operations

```
[[self.requestOperationManager operationQueue] setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];
```

this works fine for downloads and requests

Note: a good technique that i use, is to have 2 network managers, one for common requests, which has setMaxConcurrentOperationCount of 1 (i need my requests to be performed sequentially) and a downloader, which has setMaxConcurrentOperationCount to 2

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :) I didn't realize that download tasks are counted as operations in AFNetworking.

Comment: i good technique that i use, is to have 2 network managers, one for common requests, which has setMaxConcurrentOperationCount of 1 (i need my requests to be performed sequentially) and a downloader, which has setMaxConcurrentOperationCount to 2